# OpenRules rules only in a database possible?

Tags: java, rule-engine

I am experimenting with OpenRules and Java and I'd like to store all my rules in a database only. If I understand the [documentation](http://openrules.com/docs/man_repositoryDB.html) correctly, I need to have one "Main.xls" in which to store the environment settings. Now the question: Is there a way to completely circumvent this one physical .xls file?
Best case would be, if I could just call something like

```
defineOpenRulesDatabase();    
OpenRulesEngine engine = new OpenRulesEngine("db:myFile.xls");
engine.run();
```

where the method defineOpenRulesDatabase() defines all the settings which are defined in the db.properties file mentioned in the documentation.

Any idea on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. [According to the documentation](http://openrules.com/docs/man_api.html#EngineConstructors), you can pass in any URL which Java supports (i.e. anything for which `URL.openStream()` will return something useful).

So you can simply embed the [Jetty web server](http://www.mortbay.org/jetty/) in your application, create a servlet which returns the file and then call `OpenRulesEngine()` with the URL of the servlet.

Or you could download the file from the DB and use `File.createTempFile()` to create a temporary file to set up the rules engine.

Or you could file a bug against the project and ask for another constructor which allows you to pass in an `InputStream`.

[EDIT] I guess you've already seen [this document](http://openrules.com/docs/man_repositoryDB2.html) which explains how to put the rules into a database. From what I see, it's not possible to create the rule engine without an existing Main.xls file at least in your classpath.

But that file doesn't have to contain much:

> rules/main/Main.xls the main file for a rules engine to start with. It contains only the Environment table

So you can simply put a static file in the classpath and load all the rules from the DB.

Comment: According to the docs: "OpenRules uses an URL pseudo-protocol notation", that's at least how I understand it, too. The jetty version is not possible here. All three approaches have the problem of not being able to include rules from a subdirectory.
I WOULD file a bug if I got ANY response from the developers ...